# How to make extra small devices design with tailwindcss?

Tags: tailwind-css

Reading https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#overview docs
I do not see any classes for extra small devices(like iPhone 5)

So if I need to made different design for iPhone 5 and nexus 7 is there is a way to make it with
tailwindcss ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What this means is that unprefixed utilities (like `uppercase`) take effect on all screen sizes, while prefixed utilities (like `md:uppercase`) only take effect at the specified breakpoint and above.

e.g. `text-xs sm:text-base md:text-lg`. In such case font-size will follow:

- **text-xs**: All the screens starting from 0px to 639px will follow this. `font-size: 0.875rem;`
- **sm:text-base**: All screens starting from 640px to 767px will follow `font-size: 1rem;`
- **md:text-lg**:  All screens starting from 768 to 1023 will follow `font-size: 1.125rem;`

So your iPhone 5 being 320px will follow text-xs. And your Nexus 7 width 600px will still follow text-xs.

**If you still want to add additional screens then you can do**:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    screens: {
      'xxs': '540px', // min-width
    },
  }
}
```

e.g.
`text-xs xxs:text-sm`
screens will follow text-xs till 539px then Nexus 7 will follow text-sm till 639px.

Comment: Super useful, for more info check out the docs https://tailwindcss.com/docs/breakpoints